# Conditional not evaluating to true

Tags: python

According to the question, 
If the difference between the grade and the next multiple of 5 is less than 3, round grade up to the next multiple of 5 .
If the value of grade is less than 38, no rounding occurs as the result will still be a failing grade.

Here's my solution for it,

```
def gradingStudents(grades):

    for i in grades:
        if (5 * round(1 + i/5) - i) < 3 and i>= 38:
            print (5 * round(1 + i/5))
        else:
            print (i)



grades_count = int(input().strip())
grades = []

for p in range(grades_count):
    g = int(input(''))
    grades.append(g)


result = gradingStudents(grades)
```

However, on examining the output I noticed that the if condition is not working as the output generates the same grade as the input.

Comment: can you give some inputs and outputs for your code?

Comment: btw, on your last line: ‘result = ...’ will always give ‘result == None’

Comment: @KuldeepSinghSidhu 4   73,67,38,33, where 4 is the number of grades. And the output generated is same when it should have converted 73 and 38 to the next multiples.

Comment: @quamrana but the function is not supposed to return one thing it has to print out various numbers, can you please explain

Comment: If you want your function to ‘print’ then you have achieved that goal. This means it doesn’t have to return anything, so why have the ‘result = ...’?

Comment: @quamrana that was the basic template provided with the question, the real problem is that the answering which is getting print does not follow the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using modulo `%` 5 should help you. Modulo is the remainder got after the division. Example `8 % 5=3` Also the `//` operator automatically rounds down for you after the division

```
grades = [1, 9, 37, 38, 43, 47, 49, 99, 91]
rounded_grades = [grade if grade < 38 or grade % 5 in [0, 1, 2] else 5 * (grade // 5 + 1) for grade in grades]

print(grades)
print(rounded_grades)

#Output
[1, 9, 37, 38, 43, 47, 49, 99, 91]
[1, 9, 37, 40, 45, 47, 50, 100, 91]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work

```
def gradingStudents(grades):
  output =[]
  for g in filter(lambda x: x>38, grades):
     step = g + (5 - g % 5)
     output.append(step < 3 : g + step ? g)
  output.extend(filter(lambda x: x<=38, grades)):
  return output
# ... Your other code
print(gradingStudents(grades))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your approach

```
def finalGrade(grade, multiple_of=5, limit=38):
    if not grade < limit:
        grade = int(round(grade / multiple_of) * multiple_of)
    return grade

grades = [20, 34, 37, 38, 39, 41, 45, 48, 52]
finalGrades = [finalGrade(grade) for grade in grades]
# [20, 34, 37, 40, 40, 40, 45, 50, 50]
```